# Check if picturebox contains an image

Tags: visual-studio, vb6, comparison, picturebox

Is there any built-in method of `PictureBox` compontent to check if a certain portion of its content matches another `PictureBox`'s content?  e.g:

[image]

I know I can do it by comparing each individual pixel's color with `PictureBox's Point(X,Y)` Method, but that seems a bit overkill to me. Not to mention it would probably be way too slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare each pixel faster by accessing the picture's memory.
It's very easy and fast, I wrote a 2D game engine using this way when I was a new VB6 programmer. [My 2D Game Engine (yLib)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ylibgameengine/?source=directory)

All the things you got to do is that get the first pixel's address.
The below function do the job for you:

### **module1:**

```
    Public Declare Function VarPtrArray Lib "msvbvm60" Alias "VarPtr" (Ptr() As Any) As Long
    Public Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (pDst As Any, pSrc As Any, ByVal ByteLen As Long)
    Public Declare Sub ZeroMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlZeroMemory" (destination As Any, ByVal Length As Long)

    Public Type SAFEARRAYBOUND
        cElements As Long
        lLbound As Long
    End Type
    Public Type SAFEARRAY2D
        cDims As Integer
        fFeatures As Integer
        cbElements As Long
        cLocks As Long
        pvData As Long
        Bounds(0 To 1) As SAFEARRAYBOUND
    End Type
    Public Type BITMAP
        bmType As Long
        bmWidth As Long
        bmHeight As Long
        bmWidthBytes As Long
        bmPlanes As Integer
        bmBitsPixel As Integer
        bmBits As Long
    End Type
    Public Type Picture
        pic As STDPicture
        c() As Byte
        bmp As BITMAP
        SA As SAFEARRAY2D
    End Type

    Public Type lyPicture
        pic As STDPicture
        c() As Byte
        bmp As BITMAP
        SA As SAFEARRAY2D
    End Type
```

### **main form or module:**

```
    Private Sub LoadPicArray2D(val As lyPicture)
        ' get bitmap info from image box
        Call GetObjectAPI(val.pic, Len(val.bmp), val.bmp)  'dest
        ' exit if not 24-bit bitmap
        ' make the local matrix point to bitmap pixels
        If val.bmp.bmPlanes  1 Or val.bmp.bmBitsPixel  24 Or val.bmp.bmWidthBytes / val.bmp.bmWidth  3 Then
            Call Err.Raise(500, "Only 24-bit bitmaps.", "Only 24-bit bitmaps.")
        End If
        With val.SA
          .cbElements = 1
          .cDims = 2
          .Bounds(0).lLbound = 0
          .Bounds(0).cElements = val.bmp.bmHeight
          .Bounds(1).lLbound = 0
          .Bounds(1).cElements = val.bmp.bmWidthBytes
          .pvData = val.bmp.bmBits
        End With
        Call CopyMemory(ByVal VarPtrArray(val.c()), VarPtr(val.SA), 4)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim pic As lyPicture
        Set pic.pic = Form1.TargetPictureBox.Picture
        Call LoadPicArray2D(pic)

        'Just remember that the picture's memory stored top-down this mean the 
        ' upper pixel lays in lower array bound.
        ' but the array is correct in horizontal arrangement.
        ' And the array is formated BGR pic.c(0,0) = B , pic.c(1,0) = G, pic.c(2,0) = R

        pic.c(0,0) = 0                      ' the pixel at the left bottom (0, MAX_PICTURE_HEIGHT-1) of the picture.
        pic.c(0,MAX_PICTURE_HEIGHT-1) = 0     ' the pixel at (0, 0)

        ' This is very IMPORTANT to release the array at the end of the code.
        Call ZeroMemory(ByVal VarPtrArray(val.c()), 4)
        ' I dont tested this code just copied from my game engine. :D
    End Sub
```

Comment: It's better to create a SAFEARRAY with long (32 bit) values and point the pvData in that SAFEARRAY structure to lyPictures's, SAFEARRAY.pvData using this new array will gives data alignment to miximize the CPU optimization for accessing aligned pointers, then you can mask the B(Color And &HFF), G(Color And &HFF00 / &H100), B(Color And &HFF0000 / &H10000)                   NOTE that this only work if your picture is 32bit (the picture in the answer must be 24bit otherway it raises an error)